# Continue writing to a file with max size in C++

Tags: c++, file, size

I want to write to a text file with limited size (1KB for example)
and when the file reaches the maximum size I want the first half to be removed and continue writing to the file (append to what remained after removing first half).
is this possible in C++?

for example:
file that reached maximum size:
1 2 3 4 5 6
and I want to continue writing [7,9]
the new file will look like:
4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dedicated logging library for example spdlog.

https://github.com/gabime/spdlog

It has a ton of features, including rotating logs.
You can define how big a log file should be, and how many logfiles you want. It can automatically discard the older logs.

Comment: I am using easylogging++ library(https://github.com/amrayn/easyloggingpp)

Comment: https://github.com/amrayn/easyloggingpp#log-file-rotating look for the rotating section in the documentation, it seems like easylogging can do what you need out of the box

Comment: I need to define the behavior upon reaching max size, the default rollout handler in easylogging++ overwrites all the content of the file, I want it to remove only half of the file (not all of it)

Comment: how about you use logfiles half the size of the initially desired? what you are asking is problematic, because in normal text files you can not jump to the "middle". How do you even define middle? middle of number of lines? middle of characters? etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write it yourself, you have to

- keep the content you want to keep in memory, e.g. in a ring buffer.
- Whenever something is added to that buffer, you have to rewrite the file. And then flush it, otherwise it is lost if the program crashes.

This can have a big performance impact, so hande with care.